# Can we set a timer in -applicationWillTerminate method?

Tags: iphone, ios4, timer, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that pulls up data from a webpage and populates it in a UITableView. I see that my app does not terminate even after a long time after hitting the home button. I realize that if the phone was low on memory, the OS will kill the app. I do not want to do the **"Add The Key -> Application does not run in background"** in the pinfo. I would like the app to maintain state for sometime. I was wondering if we can set a timer in the                                   `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{}` 
method so that the app could terminate if it is inactive for say 1 hour and relaunch.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity why don't you want to set `Application does not run in background` to `YES`?

Comment: As I said, I am reading from a webpage and I would like my app to reflect the latest posts on the webpage. At the same time I would like to maintain state so that if they revisit the app frequently, i do not keep reloading data. Actually it is point number 2 in your answer. I am going to try saving the time in applicationDidEnterBackground: now.

Answer (score 3):

Simple & quick answer, No. You cannot run a timer for an hour after the home button is pushed. What you can do is familiarize yourself with the calls that are made when the user pushes the home button and then switches back to your app.

These are the calls you will receive now (multitasking):

```
// User taps your app icon first launch
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:

// User pushes home button
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:

// User selects your app again
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

If you do set the `Application does not run in background` key to `YES`, OR if your device does not support multitasking (i.e. iPod touch 2nd Gen) then the exact same actions will call these methods.

```
// User taps your app icon first launch
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:

// User pushes home button
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillTerminate:

// User selects your app again
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

Please note that if the OS decides to kill your app for the memory, it will not wake you up just to kill you, you are never guaranteed to receive the `applicationWillTerminate:` call.

I can think of two motivations for your question:

1) You want to save state and wanted to do it in `applicationWillTerminate:` but it's not being called. If this is the case I would suggest saving state in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` since it's called in both cases when the user pushes the home button.

2) You wanted to reload your data if the app had been inactive for over a certain amount of time. If this is the case store the current time during `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and check how much time has elapsed in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and reload if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When your app moves to the background, you can request extra time (up to, I think, 500 seconds?) to finish up some long-running task (see `-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` of `UIApplication`). But you can never schedule your app to "wake up" or be reloaded once backgrounded/terminated.

There are specific exceptions to this rule for apps that track the user's location or that need to receive incoming VOIP calls. See [Background Execution and Mutitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) section of the iOS App Programming Guide if your app qualifies.